# Exchange 2007/2010 No Free/Busy information can be retrieved

Tags: exchange-2010, exchange-2007

Exchange Enviroment: 2 Exchange 2007, 1 Exchange 2010. Clients are all outlook 2010

We have just deployed Exchange 2010 into our enviroment about an month ago. Everything was working great until we had to reboot the Exchange 2010 server yesterday and now I am unable to see the Free/busy information in the scheduling assistant of any users whose mailboxes are on the Exchange 2007 server. The server reboot was to change a bios power setting. The scheduling assistant calendar is blocked out and states an error "No information. No free\busy information could not be retrieved. The recipients server could not be contacted." The problem seems to be only in the scheduling assistant. I can see these users calendars without a problem.

This seems to only affect the users whose mailbox on the Exchange 2007 server.

My Exchange 2010 is throwing this error message since the reboot:

> Process 8080: ProxyWebRequest IntraSite from
>   S-1-5-21-648903029-188487840-239210854-2685 to
>   https://hsmercury.heartspring.org:443/ews/exchange.asmx failed. Caller
>   SIDs: NetworkCredentials. The exception returned is
>   Microsoft.Exchange.InfoWorker.Common.Availability.ProxyWebRequestProcessingException:
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException:
>   Microsoft.Exchange.InfoWorker.Common.Availability.ProxyRequestNotAllowedException:
>   Authenticated user does not have sufficient privileges to issue this
>   request. ---> Authenticated user does not have sufficient privileges
>   to issue this request.    at
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage
>   message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean
>   asyncCall)    at
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.EndInvoke(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)    at
>   Microsoft.Exchange.InfoWorker.Common.Availability.Proxy.Service.EndGetUserAvailability(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)    at
>   Microsoft.Exchange.InfoWorker.Common.Availability.FreeBusyApplication.EndProxyWebRequest(ProxyWebRequest
>   proxyWebRequest, QueryList queryList, Service service, IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)    at
>   Microsoft.Exchange.InfoWorker.Common.Availability.ProxyWebRequest.EndInvoke(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)    at
>   Microsoft.Exchange.InfoWorker.Common.Availability.AsyncWebRequest.EndInvokeWithErrorHandling().
>   The request information is ProxyWebRequest type = IntraSite, url =
>   https://hsmercury.heartspring.org:443/ews/exchange.asmx Mailbox list =
>   SMTP:jb@heartspring.org, Parameters: windowStart = 3/7/2016
>   9:00:00 AM, windowEnd = 4/6/2016 9:00:00 AM, MergedFBInterval = 30,
>   RequestedView = Detailed . --->
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException:
>   Microsoft.Exchange.InfoWorker.Common.Availability.ProxyRequestNotAllowedException:
>   Authenticated user does not have sufficient privileges to issue this
>   request. ---> Authenticated user does not have sufficient privileges
>   to issue this request.    at
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage
>   message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean
>   asyncCall)    at
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.EndInvoke(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)    at
>   Microsoft.Exchange.InfoWorker.Common.Availability.Proxy.Service.EndGetUserAvailability(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)    at
>   Microsoft.Exchange.InfoWorker.Common.Availability.FreeBusyApplication.EndProxyWebRequest(ProxyWebRequest
>   proxyWebRequest, QueryList queryList, Service service, IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)    at
>   Microsoft.Exchange.InfoWorker.Common.Availability.ProxyWebRequest.EndInvoke(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)    at
>   Microsoft.Exchange.InfoWorker.Common.Availability.AsyncWebRequest.EndInvokeWithErrorHandling()
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace --- . Name of the server where exception originated: HSMORPHEUS. Make sure that the Active Directory
>   site/forest that contain the user's mailbox has at least one local
>   Exchange 2010 server running the Availability service. Turn up logging
>   for the Availability service and test basic network connectivity.

I have added the auto configuration logs from powershell. The first one is from the Exchange 2007 server testing user1 whose mailbox is on the exchange 2007 server and user2 on the exchange 2010 server. The second one is testing the same users but on the exchange 2010 server.

Exchange 2007 autodiscover log:

```
     Welcome to the Exchange Management Shell!
```

Full list of cmdlets:          get-command
 Only Exchange cmdlets:         get-excommand
 Cmdlets for a specific role:   get-help -role *UM* or *Mailbox*
 Get general help:              help
 Get help for a cmdlet:         help  or  -?
 Show quick reference guide:    quickref
 Exchange team blog:            get-exblog
 Show full output for a cmd:     | format-list

Tip of the day #1:

To return all scripts that are found in your path, type:

Get-Command -Type ExternalScript

And for a useful shortcut, assign it in your profile as:

Function Get-Scripts { Get-Command -Type ExternalScript }

[PS] C:\Windows\system32>Test-OutlookWebServices -Identity user@heartspring.org |fl

Id      : 1003
Type    : Information
Message : About to test AutoDiscover with the e-mail address user@heartspring.org.

Id      : 1012
Type    : Warning
Message : XML>Unknown Node:AutoDiscoverSMTPAddress AutoDiscoverSMTPAddress Line:http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/autodiscover/outlook/responseschema/2006a

Id      : 1012
Type    : Warning
Message : XML>Object being deserialized: Microsoft.Exchange.Management.SystemConfigurationTasks.AutoDiscoverUser

Id      : 1012
Type    : Warning
Message : XML>Element

Id      : 1012
Type    : Warning
Message : XML>Unknown Element:System.Xml.XmlElement Line:8(8) user@heartspring.org

Id      : 1006
Type    : Information
Message : The Autodiscover service was contacted at https://exch2010.heartspring.org/Autodiscover/Autodiscover.xml.

Id      : 1016
Type    : Success
Message : [EXCH2007(1)]-Successfully contacted the AS service at https://exch2007(2).heartspring.org/EWS/Exchange.asmx. The elapsed time was 46 milliseconds.

Id      : 1015
Type    : Success
Message : [EXCH2007(1)]-Successfully contacted the OAB service at https://exch2007(2).heartspring.org/EWS/Exchange.asmx. The elapsed time was 0 milliseconds.

Id      : 1014
Type    : Success
Message : [EXCH2007(1)]-Successfully contacted the UM service at https://exch2007(2).heartspring.org/UnifiedMessaging/Service.asmx. The elapsed time was 31 milliseconds.

Id      : 1006
Type    : Success
Message : The Autodiscover service was tested successfully.

[PS] C:\Windows\system32>Test-OutlookWebServices -Identity user2@heartspring.org |fl

Id      : 1003
Type    : Information
Message : About to test AutoDiscover with the e-mail address user2@heartspring.org.

Id      : 1012
Type    : Warning
Message : XML>Unknown Node:AutoDiscoverSMTPAddress AutoDiscoverSMTPAddress Line:http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/autodiscover/outlook/responseschema/2006a

Id      : 1012
Type    : Warning
Message : XML>Object being deserialized: Microsoft.Exchange.Management.SystemConfigurationTasks.AutoDiscoverUser

Id      : 1012
Type    : Warning
Message : XML>Element

Id      : 1012
Type    : Warning
Message : XML>Unknown Element:System.Xml.XmlElement Line:8(8) user2@heartspring.org

Id      : 1006
Type    : Information
Message : The Autodiscover service was contacted at https://exch2010.heartspring.org/Autodiscover/Autodiscover.xml.

Id      : 1016
Type    : Success
Message : [EXCH2007(1)]-Successfully contacted the AS service at https://exch2010.heartspring.org/EWS/Exchange.asmx. The elapsed time was 46 milliseconds.

Id      : 1015
Type    : Information
Message : [EXCH2007(1)]-The OAB is not configured for this user.

Id      : 1014
Type    : Success
Message : [EXCH2007(1)]-Successfully contacted the UM service at https://exch2010.heartspring.org/EWS/UM2007Legacy.asmx. The elapsed time was 140 milliseconds.

Id      : 1006
Type    : Success
Message : The Autodiscover service was tested successfully.

[PS] C:\Windows\system32>

Here is log from Exchange 2010

```
     Welcome to the Exchange Management Shell!
```

Full list of cmdlets: Get-Command
Only Exchange cmdlets: Get-ExCommand
Cmdlets that match a specific string: Help 
Get general help: Help
Get help for a cmdlet: Help  or  -?
Show quick reference guide: QuickRef
Exchange team blog: Get-ExBlog
Show full output for a command:  | Format-List

Tip of the day #22:

Get all Win32 WMI information, such as Perfmon counters and local computer configurations. For example, type:

Get-WMIObject Win32_PerfRawData_PerfOS_Memory

VERBOSE: Connecting to HSMorpheus.heartspring.org
VERBOSE: Connected to HSMorpheus.heartspring.org.
[PS] C:\Windows\system32>Test-OutlookWebServices -Identity user1@heartspring.org

RunspaceId : 460387b2-ec49-4ebd-b831-8960c051fde4
Id         : 1019
Type       : Information
Message    : A valid Autodiscover service connection point was found. The Autodiscover URL on this object is https://exch2010.heartspring.org/Autodiscover/Autodiscover.xml.

RunspaceId : 460387b2-ec49-4ebd-b831-8960c051fde4
Id         : 1006
Type       : Information
Message    : Contacted the Autodiscover service at https://exch2010.heartspring.org/Autodiscover/Autodiscover.xml.

RunspaceId : 460387b2-ec49-4ebd-b831-8960c051fde4
Id         : 1016
Type       : Information
Message    : [EXCH2007(1)] The AS service is configured for this user in the Autodiscover response received from https://exch2010.heartspring.org/Autodiscover/Autodiscover.xml.

RunspaceId : 460387b2-ec49-4ebd-b831-8960c051fde4
Id         : 1015
Type       : Information
Message    : [EXCH2007(1)] The OAB service is configured for this user in the Autodiscover response received from https://exch2010.heartspring.org/Autodiscover/Autodiscover.xml.

RunspaceId : 460387b2-ec49-4ebd-b831-8960c051fde4
Id         : 1014
Type       : Information
Message    : [EXCH2007(1)] The UM service is configured for this user in the Autodiscover response received from https://exch2010.heartspring.org/Autodiscover/Autodiscover.xml.

RunspaceId : 460387b2-ec49-4ebd-b831-8960c051fde4
Id         : 1022
Type       : Success
Message    : Autodiscover was tested successfully.

RunspaceId : 460387b2-ec49-4ebd-b831-8960c051fde4
Id         : 1011
Type       : Error
Message    : When querying Availability for the recipient e-mail address user1@heartspring.org, the following error code and message were received: ErrorProxyRequestProcessingFailed:System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapE
             xception: Microsoft.Exchange.InfoWorker.Common.Availability.ProxyRequestNotAllowedException: Authenticated user does not have sufficient privileges to issue this request. ---> Authenticated user does not ha
             ve sufficient privileges to issue this request.
                at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCall)
                at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.EndInvoke(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
                at Microsoft.Exchange.InfoWorker.Common.Availability.Proxy.Service.EndGetUserAvailability(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
                at Microsoft.Exchange.InfoWorker.Common.Availability.FreeBusyApplication.EndProxyWebRequest(ProxyWebRequest proxyWebRequest, QueryList queryList, Service service, IAsyncResult asyncResult)
                at Microsoft.Exchange.InfoWorker.Common.Availability.ProxyWebRequest.EndInvoke(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
                at Microsoft.Exchange.InfoWorker.Common.Availability.AsyncWebRequest.EndInvokeWithErrorHandling(). The request information is ProxyWebRequest type = IntraSite, url = https://hsmercury.heartspring.org:443
             /ews/exchange.asmx
             Mailbox list = SMTP:user1@heartspring.org, Parameters: windowStart = 3/30/2016 1:00:00 AM, windowEnd = 3/30/2016 2:00:00 AM, MergedFBInterval = 30, RequestedView = FreeBusy
             ., inner exception: Microsoft.Exchange.InfoWorker.Common.Availability.ProxyRequestNotAllowedException: Authenticated user does not have sufficient privileges to issue this request. ---> Authenticated user d
             oes not have sufficient privileges to issue this request.

RunspaceId : 460387b2-ec49-4ebd-b831-8960c051fde4
Id         : 1025
Type       : Error
Message    : [EXCH2007(1)] Error contacting the AS service at https://exch2010.heartspring.org/EWS/Exchange.asmx. Elapsed time was 31 milliseconds.

RunspaceId : 460387b2-ec49-4ebd-b831-8960c051fde4
Id         : 1026
Type       : Success
Message    : [EXCH2007(1)] Successfully contacted the UM service at https://exch2010.heartspring.org/EWS/Exchange.asmx. The elapsed time was 15 milliseconds.

RunspaceId : 460387b2-ec49-4ebd-b831-8960c051fde4
Id         : 1004
Type       : Error
Message    : The certificate for the URL https://owa.heartspring.org/ews/exchange.asmx is incorrect. For SSL to work, the certificate needs to have a subject of owa.heartspring.org, but the subject that was found is HSM
             ercury. Consider correcting service discovery, or installing a correct SSL certificate.

RunspaceId : 460387b2-ec49-4ebd-b831-8960c051fde4
Id         : 1024
Type       : Success
Message    : [EXPR] Successfully contacted the AS service at https://owa.heartspring.org/ews/exchange.asmx. The elapsed time was 265 milliseconds.

RunspaceId : 460387b2-ec49-4ebd-b831-8960c051fde4
Id         : 1026
Type       : Success
Message    : [EXPR] Successfully contacted the UM service at https://owa.heartspring.org/ews/exchange.asmx. The elapsed time was 31 milliseconds.

RunspaceId : 460387b2-ec49-4ebd-b831-8960c051fde4
Id         : 1111
Type       : Error
Message    : When querying Availability for the recipient e-mail address user1@heartspring.org, the following error code and message were received: ErrorProxyRequestProcessingFailed:System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapE
             xception: Microsoft.Exchange.InfoWorker.Common.Availability.ProxyRequestNotAllowedException: Authenticated user does not have sufficient privileges to issue this request. ---> Authenticated user does not ha
             ve sufficient privileges to issue this request.
                at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCall)
                at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.EndInvoke(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
                at Microsoft.Exchange.InfoWorker.Common.Availability.Proxy.Service.EndGetUserAvailability(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
                at Microsoft.Exchange.InfoWorker.Common.Availability.FreeBusyApplication.EndProxyWebRequest(ProxyWebRequest proxyWebRequest, QueryList queryList, Service service, IAsyncResult asyncResult)
                at Microsoft.Exchange.InfoWorker.Common.Availability.ProxyWebRequest.EndInvoke(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
                at Microsoft.Exchange.InfoWorker.Common.Availability.AsyncWebRequest.EndInvokeWithErrorHandling(). The request information is ProxyWebRequest type = IntraSite, url = https://hsmercury.heartspring.org:443
             /ews/exchange.asmx
             Mailbox list = SMTP:user1@heartspring.org, Parameters: windowStart = 3/30/2016 1:00:00 AM, windowEnd = 3/30/2016 2:00:00 AM, MergedFBInterval = 30, RequestedView = FreeBusy
             ., inner exception: Microsoft.Exchange.InfoWorker.Common.Availability.ProxyRequestNotAllowedException: Authenticated user does not have sufficient privileges to issue this request. ---> Authenticated user d
             oes not have sufficient privileges to issue this request.

RunspaceId : 460387b2-ec49-4ebd-b831-8960c051fde4
Id         : 1125
Type       : Error
Message    : [Server] Error contacting the AS service at https://exch2010.heartspring.org/ews/exchange.asmx. Elapsed time was 31 milliseconds.

RunspaceId : 460387b2-ec49-4ebd-b831-8960c051fde4
Id         : 1126
Type       : Success
Message    : [Server] Successfully contacted the UM service at https://exch2010.heartspring.org/ews/exchange.asmx. The elapsed time was 15 milliseconds.

[PS] C:\Windows\system32>Test-OutlookWebServices -Identity user2@heartspring.org

RunspaceId : 460387b2-ec49-4ebd-b831-8960c051fde4
Id         : 1019
Type       : Information
Message    : A valid Autodiscover service connection point was found. The Autodiscover URL on this object is https://exch2010.heartspring.org/Autodiscover/Autodiscover.xml.

RunspaceId : 460387b2-ec49-4ebd-b831-8960c051fde4
Id         : 1006
Type       : Information
Message    : Contacted the Autodiscover service at https://exch2010.heartspring.org/Autodiscover/Autodiscover.xml.

RunspaceId : 460387b2-ec49-4ebd-b831-8960c051fde4
Id         : 1016
Type       : Information
Message    : [EXCH2007(1)] The AS service is configured for this user in the Autodiscover response received from https://exch2010.heartspring.org/Autodiscover/Autodiscover.xml.

RunspaceId : 460387b2-ec49-4ebd-b831-8960c051fde4
Id         : 1015
Type       : Warning
Message    : [EXCH2007(1)] The OAB service isn't configured for this user in the Autodiscover response received from https://exch2010.heartspring.org/Autodiscover/Autodiscover.xml.

RunspaceId : 460387b2-ec49-4ebd-b831-8960c051fde4
Id         : 1014
Type       : Information
Message    : [EXCH2007(1)] The UM service is configured for this user in the Autodiscover response received from https://exch2010.heartspring.org/Autodiscover/Autodiscover.xml.

RunspaceId : 460387b2-ec49-4ebd-b831-8960c051fde4
Id         : 1022
Type       : Success
Message    : Autodiscover was tested successfully.

RunspaceId : 460387b2-ec49-4ebd-b831-8960c051fde4
Id         : 1021
Type       : Information
Message    : The following web services generated errors: Oab in EXCH. Use the previous output to diagnose and correct the errors.

RunspaceId : 460387b2-ec49-4ebd-b831-8960c051fde4
Id         : 1024
Type       : Success
Message    : [EXCH2007(1)] Successfully contacted the AS service at https://exch2010.heartspring.org/EWS/Exchange.asmx. The elapsed time was 46 milliseconds.

RunspaceId : 460387b2-ec49-4ebd-b831-8960c051fde4
Id         : 1026
Type       : Success
Message    : [EXCH2007(1)] Successfully contacted the UM service at https://exch2010.heartspring.org/EWS/Exchange.asmx. The elapsed time was 31 milliseconds.

RunspaceId : 460387b2-ec49-4ebd-b831-8960c051fde4
Id         : 1004
Type       : Error
Message    : The certificate for the URL https://owa.heartspring.org/ews/exchange.asmx is incorrect. For SSL to work, the certificate needs to have a subject of owa.heartspring.org, but the subject that was found is HSM
             ercury. Consider correcting service discovery, or installing a correct SSL certificate.

RunspaceId : 460387b2-ec49-4ebd-b831-8960c051fde4
Id         : 1024
Type       : Success
Message    : [EXPR] Successfully contacted the AS service at https://owa.heartspring.org/ews/exchange.asmx. The elapsed time was 296 milliseconds.

RunspaceId : 460387b2-ec49-4ebd-b831-8960c051fde4
Id         : 1026
Type       : Success
Message    : [EXPR] Successfully contacted the UM service at https://owa.heartspring.org/ews/exchange.asmx. The elapsed time was 31 milliseconds.

RunspaceId : 460387b2-ec49-4ebd-b831-8960c051fde4
Id         : 1124
Type       : Success
Message    : [Server] Successfully contacted the AS service at https://exch2010.heartspring.org/ews/exchange.asmx. The elapsed time was 46 milliseconds.

RunspaceId : 460387b2-ec49-4ebd-b831-8960c051fde4
Id         : 1126
Type       : Success
Message    : [Server] Successfully contacted the UM service at https://exch2010.heartspring.org/ews/exchange.asmx. The elapsed time was 15 milliseconds.

[PS] C:\Windows\system32>

Comment: Okay, I think I have found my problem but not entirely sure. When I do a autoconfiguration test in outlook for any user on exchange 2007 the availability server and the OOF url are pointing to an older exchange server. It says the autodiscover found through SCP. I can't seem to find where to change this. However, I turned off IIS on the old exchange server and then ran autoconfiguration test again and the right URL's came up. I tested the scheduling assistant and it still did not work. I restarted IIS on the old exchange 2007 server and the URL's are back to pointing at the wrong server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I was able to resolve the issue. It seems that my problem was causes by rollup 12 for service pack 3 being installed a couple weeks prior. I have uninstalled rollup 12 and everything is working now. We didn't seem to have a problem with the scheduling assistant until we rebooted the server so not sure what caused the problem. At least if there was a problem before then no one caught it or it was never reported. Thanks for everyone's help on this.

Answer (score 0):

Everything is web services in the later versions of Exchange. 
Therefore the first question is do you have a proxy in your network? If so, does it have the correct exclusions in it for Exchange?

Are the URLS configured correctly for the virtual directories?

Comment: There is not a proxy. I checked all the url's and everything seems to be correct. Everything I have read seems to point to a proxy or cross forest implementations. However, we have a single domain.

Comment: Based on what you have written above, you haven't set the URLs correctly. When you are running multiple Exchange servers in the same site the Autodiscover URL should be the same on all servers in the same AD site.

get-clientaccessserver | select identity, autodiscoverserviceinternaluri

That will show you what they are currently using and then you need to change them.

Comment: Okay, I have changed the autodiscover url on all the exchange servers. The autodiscover for each server was pointing at the server it was on. So now all the autodiscover url's are pointing to my Exchange 2010 server. However, I still have the same problem of the scheduling assistant saying it can not retrieve information.

Comment: You need to check if Autodiscover is actually working correctly. Do an Autodiscover test in Outlook by holding down CTRL while right clicking on the Outlook icon in the system tray. Choose test email auto configuration. Then check the results and the logs to ensure they are what you expect.

Do you still have public folders in that environment, or have you eliminated them?

Comment: I have ran the autodiscover test on an email on the 2007 server and also one on the 2010 server. Both tests pass without any issues. We do still have the public folder database but we do not use it. It is empty.

Comment: I have added Exchange autodiscover logs above for both servers above. User 1 = 2007 mailbox, User2 = 2010 Mailbox. We have two exchange 2007 and 1 exchange 2010. However, the first exchange 2007 exchange serer (Exchange 2007(1)) has been decommissioned from running any mail or services. It is still running for backup purposes